# Why does my caesar solution for CS50 Problem Set 2 sometimes throw out random characters

Tags: c, cs50

I am working on Problem Set 2 on CS50 doing the caesar question and having some trouble.

I have tried the below code but it seems to only produce random characters for single character plaintext entries and world, say hello!

Please excuse the lack of comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//expects function to be declared later
bool validate(string key);
//Command line argument that launches with KEY
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
//reject all input that is not a single string with the key
    string key = argv[1];
    if (argc != 2)
        {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
        return 1;
        }
    else if (validate(key)==true)
    {
        string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
        char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)];
        int intkey = atoi(key);

        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
        {
            if ((plaintext[i] >= 65 && plaintext[i] <=90) || (plaintext[i] >=97 && plaintext[i] <=122))
            {
                if ((plaintext[i]+(intkey % 26) > 122) || (plaintext[i]+(intkey % 26) >90 && plaintext[i]+(intkey % 26) < 97))
                {
                    ciphertext[i] = plaintext [i] - (26 - intkey % 26);
                }
                else
                {
                    ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i] + intkey % 26;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i];

            }

        }

        printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
    }

}

bool validate(string key)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(key[i]))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == strlen(key))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I am working on Problem Set 2 on CS50 doing the caesar question and having some trouble.

I have tried the below code but it seems to only produce random characters for single character plaintext entries and world, say hello!

Please excuse the lack of comments.

Comment: What is `true` defined to be?

Comment: Substantially it is. 
Why does it matter what true is defined to be?

Comment: regarding: `if (count == strlen(key))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }`  `true` and `1` are (effectively) the same, so this function does not perform correctly.  Suggest using `true` and `false`  However, to have `true` and `false`, need to have the statement: `#include <stdbool.h>

Comment: regarding: `string key = argv[1];
    if (argc != 2) {...}`  These should be in the opposite order.  I.E. never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the 'expected' command line parameter.  In the current scenario, if the user did not enter the command line parameter, then `string key = argv[1]` will be accessing address 0, which will result in a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding: `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)` (and similar statements)  the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` which is an unsigned long int.  An code should not be comparing signed (I.E. `int` ) values with unsigned values

Comment: regarding statements like: `if ((plaintext[i] >= 65 && plaintext[i] <=90) || (plaintext[i] >=97 && plaintext[i] <=122))`  Please do NOT use hardcoded values.  Instead use literals like: `a` and `z` and `A` and `Z`

Comment: regarding; `if ((plaintext[i] >= 65 && plaintext[i] <=90) || (plaintext[i] >=97 && plaintext[i] <=122))`  strongly suggest:  `#include <ctype.h.`  and `if( isalpha( plaintext[i] )`

Answer (score 1):

`ciphertext[]` is not terminated with a null character, it even lacks the room for it, hence `printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext)` may well *produce random characters* after the actual ciphertext. This may be rectified by adding 1 to both occurrences of `strlen(plaintext)`.

Comment: Why not just make the modification `char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext) + 1] = {0};` to initialize the receiving buffer with the proper number of array elements and initialize the array to all zeros?

Comment: @Richard Chambers - Why do you decorate your suggestion (which is also correct) with the word _just_? My suggestion needs _just_ four characters added, while yours needs six. Moreover, your suggestion needlessly initializes all but one of the elements of the array.

Comment: Lol. Counting characters and claiming that 2 characters makes a difference? Easier and safer to make a single line correction that properly initializes the array, something that most modern languages do since uninitialized variables are a source of defects, than attempt to hunt through for uses of `strlen()`. If `plaintext` contains zero characters, it still works properly without going through the loop.

Comment: @Richard Chambers - By mentioning it, you seem to think that if _plaintext contains zero characters,_ only your suggestion _still works properly_, which is certainly not the case.